# Organization-Wide Email Addresses

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I am new to Organization-Wide Email Addresses. I have setup one email address in Organization-Wide Email Addresses and have selected the option as 'Allow Only Selected Profiles to Use the From Address' and have selected one profile (Non System Admin) and I am trying to trigger one workflow to send an email alert and I am using the setup Organization-Wide Email Addresse in that email alert. But even if I am triggering the workflow using another profile user which is not mentioned in Organization-Wide Email Addresses still in sender email it is using the email address defined in Organization-Wide Email Addresses. Can anyone please help me here.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because workflow running in system mode. It means it will ignore Profile and field level Security.

That's why Workflow always pick the Organization-Wide Email Addresse.

Referance link:

http://www.simplysfdc.com/2016/09/salesforce-process-builder-flow-and.html